# Check I should do to update and install python and associated packages?

Tags: python, installation, pipenv

I coded in python a few times in college for a couple of classes, each had its own requirements and preferred IDE so I know that at one point I had python, pip, pipenv all installed and working and had been using jupyter but now I'm trying to get back into it and its messy and all over the place. I've successfully opened a notebook and know what version of pip I have but can't seem to install pipenv. Should I start over and try to uninstall it all or should I try to update it? Sorry this is so broad, I'm not in college with a TA to ask these questions anymore.

Comment: Sounds like you're in the middle of a mess you don't quite understand (don't worry, that happens to all of us), but yes - I would recommend starting with a clean environment and trying to understand what changes you make as you make them. Try to find a good guide on setting up the kind of environment you want (sounds like you're after a jupyter setup) and don't just follow the instructions, but try to understand what the use is of the steps they make you go through.

Comment: How do i make sure that im starting with a clean environment with no old instances of python? Will uninstalling python, putty, etc delete all of the associated data? I want to make sure when i redownload it i dont have any paths pointing to old instances

Comment: If you install a recent version of Python, and use virtual environments, you shouldn't have too many problems. The only issue can be if a previously installed version was installed with changes to the system PATH or Python-related variables. If you use Windows, you can change those from the Start menu with System Environment Variables  (just type it, it will come up). You can remove references to Python installation folders from the PATH variable (leave the rest) and remove any Python-related variables before starting over.